# Cloth sewing problem with rigged 3d-model

Tags: rigging, cloth-simulation, collision

I have a 3D-human model with initial pose like this:

[image]

I want to rig it then change it to T-pose, by following the [YouTube tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2pTkW-1JkE). After I change it to T-pose as below:

[image]

Then I added a cloth wanting to sew them together:

[image]

However, the collision seems erroneous, because the cloth is draping around my initial pose, not the T-pose. I can saw my T-pose model in object mode, but still the initial pose in my edit mode.

[image]

How to make the cloth to be sewed together correctly? (I'm using Blender 2.80, not the latest one). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a copy of the model, apply its armature modifier and use it to build the clothes.

Comment: A simple press on "Apply" solves the problem, appreciate your help!